# Writing this Matrix in Latex

Tags: matrices

I want to write this matrix in Latex: [image]

I wrote this code:

```
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \ldots 0 & 0 \ldots 0 & d_{i,L} & * \ldots *\\
0 \ldots 0 & 0  \ldots d_{i,L-1} & * & * \ldots *\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 \ldots d_{i,1} & * \ldots * & *  & * \ldots *\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

How do I improve upon it?/

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some more aligns:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathdots}

\begin{document}
$$\Delta(\left|v_{i}\right>)=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & d_{i,L} & * & \ldots & *\\
0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & \ldots & d_{i,L-1} & * & * & \ldots & *\\
\vdots & \iddots & \vdots & \vdots & \iddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \iddots & \vdots\\
0 & \ldots & 0 & d_{i,2} & \ldots & * & * & * & \ldots & *\\
0 & \ldots & d_{i,1} & * & \ldots & * & * & * & \ldots & *\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
\end{document}
```